# Validate that two columns are unique themselves and from each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working an a Rails application where when a user creates a product, that product is given a random url in the column `original_url`. The user can later pick a custom url, which will be saves in `custom_url`.

The product will be able to be accessed from both the original url and the custom url. I just can't figure out how to keep the columns not only unique amongst themselves, but also amongst each other. I did discover `:scope`, but that doesn't achieve what I have in mind.

Example of what can't happen:

`original_url: Ab | custom_url: nil`

`original_url: Bc | custom_url: Ab`

Another example of what can't happen:

`original_url: Ab | custom_url: nil`

`original_url: Ab | custom_url: nil`

Example of what can happen:

`original_url: Ab | custom_url: nil`

`original_url: Bc | custom_url: De`

`original_url: Gh | custom_url: nil`

Comment: what do you want original_url == custom_url ?

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I updated the question to hopefully make it more obvious what I want (added some more examples).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best choice is to write a customized validation block/method, like:

```
validate do
  if Product.where(original_url: original_url, custom_url: original_url).size > 0 ||
    Product.where(original_url: custom_url, custom_url: custom_url).size > 0
  errors.add(:base, 'Original url and custom url must be unique.')
end
```

Another solution is to create a model for urls, then let `Product` `has_many :urls`.

Answer (score 1):

A super simple hack is to add a unique prefix to original_url and custom_url

Say, your original original_url is 6 digits, like 'foobar', then the new origina_url will be 'ofoobar'. And custom_url, if generated, should start with "c" which is "cfoobar".

By this you only need to validate origina_url and custom_url separately and normally, only add a pattern to fit the prefix.